# Audiorecorder in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, real-time

I'm new to matlab. Essentially i want to get audio signal of fixed length (10 seconds) from microphone, perform some operations and play output sound. I was trying to use audiorecorder something like this:

`y = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 1)`
`record(y, 10);`
`% signal processing;`
`play(output);`

The problem is it's asking for a user prompt to stop recording first and then go to next stage. I just want it to record (on user prompt) whatever it gets for 10 sec and stop automatically. Then proceed to next stages and play final output, all without further user prompt. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: If you're going to be working with audio a lot, consider looking into Matt Frear's pa-wavplay package instead of audiorecorder. Audiorecorder's not really intended for hardcore audio work, but for recording clips of your microphone you'll be fine :) [pa-wavplay info here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4017)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use audiorecorders [recordblocking](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audiorecorder.recordblocking.html) method to record for a specfied amount of time, and wait until that time has elapsed.

So, your new code would look like:

```
a = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 1)

% record for 10 seconds before moving on    
recordblocking(a, 10);

% signal processing;

play(a);
```

Comment: Thanks, but another problem is i am using Macintosh and most multichannel audio recording in matlab is only for windows. I have a 4-microphone array and i want to use each one separately. But i cannot specify deviceID in audiorecorder as it doesnt work with Macintosh. Is it possible?